# Possible to store an arraylist that carry data to QR Code?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, qr-code, zxing

Is it possible to store an `arrayList` to QR Code? The `arrayList` will carry data.
For example, I decode the 8 numbers of QR Codes and then I got the content(might be `String` or `int`) from those QR Code. Then the next thing is I store the content to an `ArrayList` and store the `ArrayList` to QR Code.

So if we scan the QR Code and the result will be like the 1st content is "1st content", then the 2nd content will be "2nd content", some sort like that ?

Ps: I am using Zxing library to generate and scan the QR Code.

Comment: You can store json string in a single QR code, decode it when scaning.

Comment: If storing json, can I decode it and check all the content like the 1st content is "..." 2nd content is "..." ?